# TinkerPop3 compatibility with Frames?

Tags: tinkerpop3, tinkerpop-frames

I have following below 2 queries related to TinkerPop 3:

1) Which Frames version is compatible with tinkerpop3?

2) TinkerPop3 official documentation states that the Frames feature has merged into "Traversal" but I could not found any information on that. So, please help me on this how we will implement it using Java.

Answer (score 1):

Frames is no longer supported for TP3 unfortunately. But that shouldn't make you upset, there is an alternative.

Have you checked [Peapod](https://github.com/bayofmany/peapod)? It does what Frames do but for Tinkerpop3.

```
@Vertex
public abstract class Person {
  public abstract String getName();
  public abstract void setName(String name);

  public abstract List<Knows> getKnows();
  public abstract Knows getKnows(Person person);
  public abstract Knows addKnows(Person person);
  public abstract Knows removeKnows(Person person);
}

@Edge
public abstract class Knows {
  public abstract void setYears(int years);
  public abstract int getYears();
}
```

and then you could easily use it like this

```
Graph g = //define your graph heere
FramedGraph graph = new FramedGraph(g, Person.class.getPackage());
Person marko = graph.v(1, Person.class);
```

For more information, have a look [here](http://bayofmany.github.io/).

Disclaimer: I'm a contributor to Peapod.